# Crash on App Launch in IOS 6 with using UIMotionEffect Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am using UIInterpolatingMotionEffect for creating a custom AlertView in iOS 7. It works fine in iOS 7 devices but crashing on devices with iOS 6 or less with the error given below.

Any help would be appreciated.

**dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIInterpolatingMotionEffect**

Referenced from: /Users/kashif/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/653D5FF9-1B55-4FFA-B608-4B2077CD0DFA/MyTest.app/MyTest

Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /Users/kashif/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/653D5FF9-1B55-4FFA-B608-4B2077CD0DFA/MyTest.app/MyTest

Comment: UIMotionEffect is available from iOS7 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIMotionEffect` is indeed only available in iOS 7. To make your app work under iOS 6, select `UIKit.framework` in your project file list, then change its linking state (shown in the right sidebar) from *Required* to *Optional*. But you'll need a different code path (that doesn't make use of `UIMotionEffect`) for iOS 6 then.

Comment: That worked in my case, thanks. But is there any disadvantage in making UIKit optional ?

Comment: There is no reason to make `UIKit` optional. `UIKit` was available in iOS 6.

Comment: wrong - it prevents linker issues just like the one described in the question. `UIKit` itself was available in iOS 6, but not all classes, so these need to be marked optional.

Comment: NO NO NO! Bad idea! Just use checks for the os version, there is a great example of this in Apple's developer videos... you shouldn't need to make UIKit optional for this, and yes there are down sides, a lot of my apps were rejected as they crashed upon launch when i made UIKit optional. Instead of making it optional include an if statement along these lines:

`if (NSClassFromString(UIMotionEffect)){
    // Allocate motion effect in here.
}`

Comment: I never had problems with making UIKit optional. Are you sure that your crashes wer not due to a side effect with something else? Or do you have anything else to back up your claim that (and why) making UIKit optional is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the header line in the class.

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) @interface UIMotionEffect : NSObject <NSCopying, NSCoding>
```

It is avaiable from iOS7 only.

Comment: I know its not available in iOS 7, i have added check #if (defined(__IPHONE_7_0)) before using it in my code but with no luck.